# Variable changed after function gets called again in C

Tags: c, struct

I created a struct and a function that returns that struct.
Afterwards I'm calling that function twice, each time assigned to a different variable.
The problem is that the first variable changes after the second run.
What am I missing here?

code:

```
struct text_and_len {
    char* text;
    int len;
};

struct text_and_len get_text_and_length(){
    int len;
    scanf("%d ", &len);

    char text[len];
    fgets(text, len+1, stdin);
    return (struct text_and_len) {text, len};
}

void get_input_and_check_is_within(){
    struct text_and_len b = get_text_and_length();
    printf("%s \n", b.text);

    struct text_and_len a = get_text_and_length();

    printf("%s \n", a.text);
    printf("%s \n", b.text);
```

this will first print the b.text, but then will print the a.text twice.

Comment: `fgets(text, len+1, stdin);` - why `len+1`? Your buffer length is `len`.

Comment: You are returning a struct with a pointer  `text` which is pointing to a local array, and is invalid outside the function.

Comment: @EugeneSh. shouldn't I keep extra 1 for the enter? It completely breaks without it.

Comment: Your code has multiple issues, each is leading to undefined behavior, so it "breaks". From the docs: *fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters* - so it will read *one less* than the size passed, and add a terminating `\0`., in total `len+1` at max, and it will overflow your buffer.

Comment: It's broken even without the extra `+1`. You're returning a struct which contains a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope (IOW ceases to exist) at the end of the function. You need to allocate memory in `get_text_and_length`, like `char *text = malloc(len);`. Don't forget to free that memory at some point (but not in the `get_text_and_length` function of course.

Comment: Got your second point, and it works, but not the first one tbh, If you can explain it once again it would be great, thanks!

Comment: @Ben what second point and what first one? Please be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

These lines used in `get_text_and_length()()`:

```
char text[len];
fgets(text, len+1, stdin);//over writes buffer by at least 1, 2 if wanting a C string.  Will cause undefined behavior.(UB)
```

will potentially allow user to enter input that would over write the buffer.
The code as is also includes variables that reach end of life before they are needed else where, resulting in predictable, but unwanted behavior.
Also the member in the struct `char* text;` requires memory be allocated before being written to.  Thus will also require freeing.

Below is your code refactored to address these, with some other modifications to the prototypes and calling methods that simplify the writing of the code...

```
struct text_and_len {
    char* text;
    int len;
};

void get_text_and_length(struct text_and_len *b){
    printf("Enter max length of input string\n");
    scanf("%d ", &(b->len));

    //b->text[b->len];//VLA, but has already been declared as char *
    b->text = malloc(b->len + 2);//room for NULL terminator AND newline
    memset(b->text, 0, b->len+2);//zero variable to all NULL
    //fgets(text, len+1, stdin);//text has no memory
                                //and as is would have over-written 
                                //buffer - UB
    printf("Enter string no longer than max length\n");
    fgets(b->text, b->len+2, stdin);//note len+2 provides room
                                  //for len char + NULL + newline
}

void get_input_and_check_is_within(struct text_and_len *b){
    get_text_and_length(b);

    printf("max length: %d \n", b->len);
    printf("text entered:%s \n", b->text);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct text_and_len a = {0};
    get_input_and_check_is_within(&a);
    free(a.text);//allocated in get_text_and_length()
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you allocate `b->len + 1`, you have space to do `fgets(b->text, b->len + 1, ...`, and the user actually has the right to expect that you allocate `b->len +2` and use `b->len + 2` in the fgets, since the user probably doesn't count the terminating newline in their calculation of the length.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - Thanks.  I have seen this suggestion before :)  I'll get it eventually.   edited it in.